# SpaCy-nightly init fill-config command gives a ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, command-line, spacy

Currently I'm trying to train a NLP model with spacyNightly. On the spacyNightly site I've created a config_base.cfg with help of the quickstart.

On the commandline I am trying to auto fill it with the following code:

```
python -m spacy init fill-config base.cfg config.cfg --diff
```

After running I receive this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Elske nijhof\.conda\envs\SpaCyNightlyenv\lib\runpy.py", line 188, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "C:\Users\Elske nijhof\.conda\envs\SpaCyNightlyenv\lib\runpy.py", line 147, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "C:\Users\Elske nijhof\.conda\envs\SpaCyNightlyenv\lib\runpy.py", line 111, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "C:\Users\Elske nijhof\.conda\envs\SpaCyNightlyenv\lib\site-packages\spacy\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from . import pipeline  # noqa: F401
  File "C:\Users\Elske nijhof\.conda\envs\SpaCyNightlyenv\lib\site-packages\spacy\pipeline\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .attributeruler import AttributeRuler
  File "C:\Users\Elske nijhof\.conda\envs\SpaCyNightlyenv\lib\site-packages\spacy\pipeline\attributeruler.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .pipe import Pipe
  File "spacy\\pipeline\\pipe.pyx", line 8, in init spacy.pipeline.pipe
  File "C:\Users\Elske nijhof\.conda\envs\SpaCyNightlyenv\lib\site-packages\spacy\training\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .corpus import Corpus  # noqa: F401
  File "C:\Users\Elske nijhof\.conda\envs\SpaCyNightlyenv\lib\site-packages\spacy\training\corpus.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .augment import dont_augment
  File "C:\Users\Elske nijhof\.conda\envs\SpaCyNightlyenv\lib\site-packages\spacy\training\augment.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .example import Example
  File "spacy\\training\\example.pyx", line 10, in init spacy.training.example
  File "C:\Users\Elske nijhof\.conda\envs\SpaCyNightlyenv\lib\site-packages\spacy\training\align.py", line 5, in <module>
    import tokenizations
  File "C:\Users\Elske nijhof\.conda\envs\SpaCyNightlyenv\lib\site-packages\tokenizations\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .tokenizations import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tokenizations.tokenizations'
```

I installed spacyNightly in a new environment and the installation looked fine.

Is there someone who could help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install [pytokenizations](https://pypi.org/project/pytokenizations/).

```
pip install pytokenizations
```

Comment: Pytokenizations is already installed. When trying to install it again, I'll get the same error (spaCyNightlyenv) C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install pytokenizations
Requirement already satisfied: pytokenizations in c:\users\elske nijhof\.conda\envs\spacynightlyenv\lib\site-packages (0.7.2)'

Comment: It looks like spacy nightly doesn't use pytokenizations any more so you should update nightly to the most recent version if you haven't already done so. [source](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/pull/6293/commits/14d6e13528c5d2da06b050e860f2d9ed630d955a)